# Mobilejquery show nothing on Internet explorer

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to mobilejquery, i made a trial page, it works fine in all browsers apart from Internet explorer 8.0/7.0, both are showing the empty page. and it throw the error as :

```
Webpage error details:

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Wed, 8 Feb 2012 09:59:25 UTC


Message: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.
Line: 3175
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js
```

As well this is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blufin-Mobile application</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/blufin-app.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Welcome to Blufin Game</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>This is the sample work of the Blufin Game!</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h4>Page footer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

is there any issue on my code? or in jquerymobile, if so any workaround to fix it..?

In case i removed jquerymobile.js, no error found.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to your problem or not, but you might want to try using the recommended jquery version: for jqm 1.0: 1.6.4

Comment: we stopped testing jQuery mobile on IE since lots of stuff doesn't work, if it works fine on all the phones and Chrome/FF why bother I guess - it's intended for the phone and you can for the most part develop in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  It turns out that the combination of jquery mobile and the latest version of jquery causes issues with ie.  Just link to jquery version 1.6.4 and the problem should go away, at least it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing issue.  I've been trying various permutations of jQuery and jQuery Mobile with IE 11, for example JQM 1.2.0 with jQuery 1.6.4 but still get just a white screen with the spinning "wait forever" graphic...

Everything works fine with the current versions of JQM and jQuery on every other browser I've tested - Firefox, Safari for Windows. Safari for iOS, Chrome...